# text align right in a span

Tags: html, css, mautic

I am a little bit in doubt how I solve this the best way. In the footer of this page: [Portfolio](https://vouzalis.com/index.php) , there is the following:

> 04-11-2016    : Design In Portfolio
>
> 05-11-2016    : Hvad er Mautic?
>
> 06-11-2016  : Some text

I would like that the date is right aligned, but only the date. There I thought I could set it in a span? I tried with this html but that is of course not a solution:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="footeritem">
        <h4>Nyheder</h4>
        <ul class="popular-posts">
            <li>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    Design In Portfolio
                    <span class="newsDate">06-11-2016</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    Hvad er Mautic?
                    <span class="newsDate">06-11-2016</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    Some text
                    <span class="newsDate">06-11-2016</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.newsDate {
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried float: right?

Comment: Of course, thank you a lot, that is working. Is it okay to set that in a span?

Comment: Yeah :P no problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Its contained inside a block element so add `"float: right"` to those spans to get your right alignment =).

Edit. Someone shot down the float idea in a now deleted comment. Floating does present some layout ugliness for when your text on the left becomes too large. You could instead use a fancy flex solution that will hold up across different context a bit better.

For flex, set the anchor to `"display: flex"` and the span to `"flex: 1; text-align: right; white-space: nowrap;"`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this solution. I will just read a little bit up on that

Comment: Thanks for this solution. However, in my scenario I had some problems that the part in the span was suddenly vertical-aligned to top when I had text spanning multiple lines. I solved this by adding "align-self: flex-end;"

Answer (score 17):

You can try this:-

```
 float:right;
```

Answer (score -4):

1. Put your span outside the link
2. Make sure your li is in display block (or inline-block with defined width)
3. float right your span

**CSS**

```
span { float: right; }
```

**HTML**

```
    <li>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            Hvad er Mautic? &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
        </a>
        <span class="newsDate">06-11-2016</span>
    </li>
```

Comment: You create CSS style for all spans that use that CSS but you have class. Maybe you can use that class in the CSS declaration as "span.newsDate { float: right; }" which will change the style only in <span class="newsDate">.