# Align one <span> to right margin of <div> element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code, it is a `<div>` element which contains two `<span>` elements separated by a `<br>`

```
<div style="background-color: orange;">
    <span>Foo</span><br>
    <span>Bar</span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/73bwrdxk/

Not sure if relevant but I am using Bootstrap 3.

I would like that the second `<span>` (the one with the text `Bar`) will be right aligned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [text align right in a span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427457/text-align-right-in-a-span)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [**`float`**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)

```
style="float: right;"
```

---

[**Using In-line style tag**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)

```
<div style="background-color: orange;">
    <span>Foo</span>
    <br>
    <span style="float: right;">Bar</span>
</div>
```

**[Using bootstrap (`pull-left` and `pull-right`)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-floats)**

```
<div style="background-color: orange;">
    <span>Foo</span>
    <br>
    <span class="pull-right">Bar</span>
</div>
```

---

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7f40emao/1/) ([**Using In-line style tag**](https://jsfiddle.net/7f40emao/1/))

Answer (score 2):

**use bootstrap class pull-right in span to make its align right**

```
<div style="background-color: orange;">
    <span>Foo</span><br>
    <span class="pull-right">Bar</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.spanl{
float:right;

}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: orange;" class=" ">
<span>Foo</span>
<span class="spanl">Bar</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I need `Bar` to be BELOW `Foo`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply replace with this code:

```
<div style="background-color: orange;">
    <span>Foo</span><br>
    <span style="float:right">Bar</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You ca make use of `float` property and clearfix. Using Float on child Elements collapse the parent element size. So you need to add clearfix class to parent to avoid collapse situation.

```css
.clearfix::after{
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.floatRight{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: orange;" class="clearfix">
<span>Foo</span>
<span class="floatRight">Bar</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I need `Bar` to be BELOW `Foo`